# Join string with delimiters

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a string array : `Arrays.asList("str1", "str2", "str3", "str4");`

And I want converti it as string with delimmotors, like this :

"str1,str2,str3,str4"

How I can do it without iterating my list ?

Comment: Why don't you want to iterate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes with Java 8 :

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("str1", "str2", "str3", "str4");
String result = String.join(",", list);
```